How to list the keys available in a object in jolt
I am trying to add all the keys available in input to the object named original and these are intialised to {}.
Input:
{
  "PartyStatus": {
    "item": [
      {
        "RleStsVal": {
          "prtyRleStsVal": "0001",
          "prtyRleStsTyp": "Active"
        },
        "PrtyRleStgCd": {
          "PrtyRleStgTp": "0002",
          "PrtyRleStgDesc": "Prospect"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Expected Output:
{
  "PartyStatus": {
    "item": [
      {
        "RleStsVal": {
          "prtyRleStsVal": "0001",
          "prtyRleStsTyp": "Active"
        },
        "RleStgCd": {
          "PrtyRleStgTp": "0002",
          "PrtyRleStgDesc": "Prospect"
        },
        "$original": {
          "RleStgCd": {},
          "RleStsVal": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

in the output, $original object should have all the keys of the objects available initialised with with empty braces

You can use the following transformation :
[
  {//generate an object with key "$original"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "PartyStatus": {
        "item": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&4.&3[&2].&1.&",
              "$": "&4.&3[&2].\\$original.&" //$ character shold be escaped, since it's a reserved one as a wildcard
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//overwrite the values of the newly generated atributes by {} respectivly
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "PartyStatus": {
        "item": {
          "*": {
            "\\$original": {
              "*": {} 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


jolt is not working when input is like below
{
"PartyStatus": {
"item": [
{
"RleStsVal": {
"prtyRleStsVal": "0001",
"prtyRleStsTyp": "Active"
},
"RleStgCd": {
"PrtyRleStgTp": "0002",
"PrtyRleStgDesc": "Prospect"
},
"PrtyRleStgVal": "ProspectVal"
  }
]

}
}
